# Middleware created in the construct method in controller throwing an error

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am trying to limit users to certain methods in my controller, I thus had to create a middleware in my construct method in my controller, it worked at first then when I wrote the second middleware all hell broke loose.

```
 public function __construct(){
    /*
        @Thirdwrist
        This is a a middleware that checks if a user has registered
        a profile, if the user is registered it redirects to the index
        of the profile controller, else it allows the user to access the 
        methods.
    */ 
    $this->middleware(function($request, $next){

        $id = Auth::id();
        if(Profile::where('user_id',$id)->count()){

            return redirect()->Route('profile.index');
        }
        else{
            return $next;
        }
    })->only(['create', 'store']);


    /*
        @Thirdwrist
        Middleware which checks if the user has a profile
    */ 
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next){
        if (!Profile::where('user_id',Auth::id())->count()) {

            return redirect()->Route('profile.create');
        }
    })->except(['create', 'store']);
}
```

**Error**

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>   Closure object cannot have properties

it points to this code in laravel

```
 {
    $config = config('session');

    $response->headers->setCookie(
        new Cookie(
            'XSRF-TOKEN', $request->session()->token(), $this->availableAt(60 * $config['lifetime']),
            $config['path'], $config['domain'], $config['secure'], false, false, $config['same_site'] ?? null
        )
    );

    return $response;
}
```

}

the line with the **$response->headers->setCookie**

Comment: can you show more about the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `$request` to the `$next` closure.

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
    $id = Auth::id();

    if (Profile::where('user_id', $id)->count()) {
        return redirect()->Route('profile.index');
    }

    return $next($request);
})->only(['create', 'store']);
```